# Subscription based In App purchase in IPhone app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes

I plan to sell Stories using in app purchase subscription model . my each story Content contains imges, text , audio and videos
Before proceeding to the development , i still have the below questions

1) Even for subscription based in app purchase, do we need to submit the contents like images , text, audio and videos for review?

2) We will be updating the contents periodically say for example 2days once we will be updating the stories  so all the time do we need to get the contents to be reviewed again and again all the time.

3) Can we sell each story with images, text,audio and video ( One Story = Images + Text + Audio + Video) via subscription based in app purchase

Please let me know your thoughts